# Enumerate possible ways to choose n elements from n columns where each column is a variable length

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSMutable array of N elements. Each element is also an NSMutable array of k NSNumbers.  In other words a table with variable length columns.

I need to generate a new array containing all the possible ways of selecting one element per column.

Example:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
2         2
```

Result:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 2
2 1 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method will iterate through the possible column indices that you want to take, beginning with `[0,0,...,0]`:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)nextIndex:(NSMutableArray *)prevIndex {
    NSMutableArray newIndex = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:prevIndex];
    int numCols = [bigArray count];
    for (int i=numCols-1; i>=0; --i) {
        if ([[prevIndex objectAtIndex:i] intValue] < [[bigArray objectAtIndex:i] count]-1) {
            [newIndex replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[prevIndex objectAtIndex:i] intValue]+1]];
            for (int j=i+1; j<numCols; ++j) {
                [newIndex replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
            }
            return newIndex;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

To use it, do something along these lines:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)matrixArray {
    NSMutableArray *matrix = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *index = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int numCols = [bigArray count];
    for (int i=0; i<numCols; ++i) {
        [index addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }
    while (index != nil) {
        [values removeAllObjects];
        for (int i=0; i<numCols; ++i) {
            [values addObject:[bigArray objectAtIndex:[index objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }
        [matrix addObject:values];
        index = [self nextIndex];
    }
    return [matrix autorelease];
}
```

Note that I did not test or debug this code, it's just to give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! With a few bug fixes this works like a charm! The [values addObject line needs an additional objectAtIndex to get the value from the sub array.  [Matrix addObject:values] should be [matrix addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:values]]; otherwise you get a pointer to the same row.